# Alamofire 4.0 RequestRetrier should(_,retry,with,completion) not being called

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using the `RequestRetrier` of Alamofire 4.0 to control the retrying of requests for expired access token. I am following the documentation [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests).

I have a very similar implementation to the example available in the documentation `OAuth2Handler` which implements `RequestAdapter` and `RequestRetrier`.

The issue I am encountering is that `func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion)` is never being called. The `adapt` method of the `RequestAdapter` implementation does get called though.

Debugging, I see that `SessionDelegate` only calls `should(_,retry,with,completion)` when there is an error, but requests that return status codes related to Authorization issues, don't seem to generate errors, so that method never gets called.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe you are not getting an error. 400 responses aren't considered as error by `Alamofire`. In case you want get an error when receiving a 400 code you should chain `validate()` to the request.
If this is your case you can find more information [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/536).

Comment: Forgot to call validate! That was it, thanks @crisisGriega!

Answer (score 13):

Following the example in the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests) exactly , mine didn't work.I was already using `validate()` as shown in the example.

```
let sessionManager = SessionManager()
sessionManager.adapter = oauthHandler
sessionManager.retrier = oauthHandler
let urlString = "\(baseURLString)/some/endpoint"

sessionManager.request(urlString).validate().responseJSON { response in
debugPrint(response)
}
```

Although , after replacing `SessionManager()` with `Alamofire.SessionManager.default` , the method `func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion)` 
gets invoked.

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
```

Comment: Have you figured out why this is happening, I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Andrea No I haven't.

Comment: Needed that too, to make it work: let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

Comment: try sessionManager.validate(statusCodes: [200])