# Alamofire: Handle error globally

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to handle Alamofire errors globally, similar to this: [AFNetworking: Handle error globally and repeat request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893837/afnetworking-handle-error-globally-and-repeat-request)

One use case would be to detect a `400 status code` error (unauthorized / expired API token) and present the login page. Is there a way to hook on something in the Alamofire core or should I create my own error handler and always call `validate().response()` manually each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you will have to handle that logic in your own custom `response` implementation. We (the Alamofire TC) are currently working on ways that we can make this process easier, but it's very difficult to get right without complicating the rest of the APIs. We're still a ways off yet.

With that said, I built an OAuth 2.0 system that handles this process in a different non-open-source library. It is possible, it's just difficult to do. You will need to hook into the `response` closure for all requests that could 401. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28748683/1342462) for a full breakdown of how to do this.

Hopefully that helps shed some light. Cheers

Comment: Nope, not yet. This is certainly something we'd love to add as a component library to Alamofire core, but it's not high on our priority list at the moment.